# Laravel 8.X question: Making the changes to the database directly without migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I made some changes [mostly setting the default to null,etc] to the database tables directly[without using the migrate]. Is it important to run migrate after it?  Can you please tell what are the steps I need to follow now to do the migration if it necessary?

Comment: Its not important to change it with the laravel migrate,  you can change it from your dstabase too

Answer (score 1):

While it's **NOT MANDATORY** to make all changes to database via migration files - incorporating all changes to database in migration files have benefits.

Whatever changes you made manually to the database directly will not be part of your migrations.

After making such changes it is not required to run `php artisan migrate` even if you do it will show a message "Nothing to Migrate" - you actually don't need to do anything.

However consider this, you are in active development phase and maybe at some point after the manual changes you may require to refresh the database running `php artisan migrate:fresh` - **then you will loose all the changes you made manually to the database**

That's why whatever changes you make to the database - it's better to do via migration files. Even if you do some manual change to the database ensure you incorporate the same in the migration files.

By doing so you may avoid ending up in a situation where you ran `php artisan migrate:fresh` and completely forgot what changes you made to database manually earlier and things are not working as earlier due to the same.

Ensuring that all changes to the database are incorporated in migration files also ensure that during testing when you test against a testing specific database the database structure is same.

Comment: `php artisan migrate:fresh` will drop all tables and re-run all of your migrations. [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/seeding#running-seeders)

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with @Donkarnash answer, but have seen it done both ways. Given the following migration:

```
Schema::create('examples', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('example_text');
});
...
```

If you run `php artisan migrate` at this point, you will end up with an `examples` table that doesn't allow `example_text` as `null`. If you later decide that you want `example_text` to be `nullable()`, then you can do 1 of 3 things:

---

First, you can create a new Migration to modify the column to `nullable()`:

```
Schema::table('examples', function(Blueprint $table) {
  $table->string('example_text')->nullable()->change();
});
```

Then, run `php artisan migrate` to update the column.

---

Second, you can rollback your migrations, modify and re-run. Run `php artisan migrate:rollback`, then modify your migration:

```
Schema::create('examples', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('example_text')->nullable();
});
...
```

And re-run `php artisan migrate`. Note, **this will nuke everything from your database**, so this is not recommended if you have data in production/don't want to lose everything.

---

Third, manually modify through your database UI and update migration. In this approach, you simply modify the database directly, update the migration, but don't re-run migrations.

```
Schema::create('examples', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('example_text')->nullable();
});
...
```

And that's it. The main catch is that if you have this database in multiple places (local, staging, production), then you need to manually update each one.

Comment: Fourth, write a migration to modify the column `Schema::table('examples', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('example_text', 50)->nullable()->change();
});`

Comment: That's point 1 :P "First, you can create a new Migration to modify the column to nullable():"

Comment: No it's different from point 2 .You can create a new migration file with the modification and then run php artisan migrate there's no need to rollback the earlier migrations : docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: Sorry, I typed 2, but edited my comment. Point 1 is **exactly what you're describing**

Comment: Okay sorry my bad. But the point is that with an approach to make any changes via migrations or incorporating all manual changes in migration files has benefits and as you pointed put in closing line it becomes easy to maintain the same structure across various environments - development/testing, staging, production

Comment: Yup! Like I said, I agree with everything you said; I was simply providing a code scenario that I've encountered done both ways before.

Comment: I agree code scenario makes it more clearer. And sometimes when doing manual testing like making minor change and refreshing the browser it make be easy & probably inevitable to make manual change to database. But then incorporating it in migration later on would ensure that the manual change is not forgotten while replicating in different environments

Comment: Exactly, you got it :) There's definitely pros and cons to each, and it's highly dependant on your development situation (solo project for fun, group project with no production, enterprise software development as part of a team, etc etc)