# Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am following Laravel-8 tutorial from Scratch. Now I am in this tutorial [https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/30[][1]](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/30%5B%5D%5B1%5D). But when I am folowing I have

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'omnis' for key 'categories_name_unique' (SQL: insert into `categories` (`name`, `slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (omnis, vero-ipsam-atque-et-iusto-consequatur-inventore-quam-temporibus, 2021-08-06 05:40:33, 2021-08-06 05:40:33))' Error
>
> Here I want to create 10 posts where category_id is 1 so I run php artisan tinker and App\Models\Post::factory(10)->create(['category_id'=> 1]); Then I have the following error.

This is my categories table

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is CategoryFactory.php

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this -> faker -> word(),
            'slug' => $this -> faker -> slug()
        ];
    }
```

This is PostFactory.php

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'category_id' => Category::factory(),
            'title' => $this -> faker ->sentence(),
            'slug' => $this -> faker -> slug(),
            'excerpt' => $this -> faker -> sentence(),
            'body' => $this ->faker -> paragraph()
        ];
    }
```

This is Post.php Models

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything unclear about the error? You insert a duplicated value for the column `category.name` anywhere in your application

Comment: Looks  to me like you try to create a new category with the same name every time you create a post. an the name is marked as unique

Comment: It's strange you are getting duplicates when just creating 10 rows. But you can use `$this-> faker->unique()->word(),` to get unique values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel SQLSTATE\[23000\]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948524/laravel-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry)

Comment: Can Vural .... I have done this in my categoryFactory.php you can see this but its not worikng.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution In command App\Models\Post::factory(10)->create(['category_id' => 1]); I was miss spell category_id.

Answer (score -1):

Why you keep this table as unique if you keep like so you can use same name only once. remove unique(), that why this error shows when you try to use same name twice it is not allow you to insert data only once you can insert.

```
$table->string('name')->unique();
```

TO

```
$table->string('name');
```

Comment: The problem is not that the name is unique, but that he tries to create multiple categories with the same name instead of using the existing category id, this will remove the error, but will NOT give the expected result. Please read the complete question before answering: 'Here I want to create 10 posts where category_id is 1 '